# Interop question about StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, interop, marshalling, managed

I am calling a C# method from C code.

The C# method:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void p_func(StringBuilder arg);

    public static void callback(StringBuilder arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.ToString());
    }
```

The C method:

```
extern "C" void  c_method(p_func f)
{
 char msg[4];
 ::strcpy(msg,"123");
 char* p="123"; 
 f(msg); // this is ok
    f(p);   //Error: Attempted to read or write protected memory!
}
```

But if I use String instead of StringBuilder as below in my C# method declaration, f(p) and f(msg) both work.  Why?

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void p_func(String arg);

    public static void callback(String arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.ToString());
    }
```

### Note

the calling logic is like this:

c_method()---->delegate p_func--->callback()

not the reverse.

I checked the *arg* in the *callback(StringBuilder arg)*, the *Length, MaxCapacity, Capacity* are all the same for char *p or msg[]. Only that *p leads to the exception. Why?

Comment: "I am calling a C# method from C code." - one question, why? :)

Comment: I don't know much C++, but what is your definition of p_func in your C++ app? StringBuilder gets marshalled as a special case...

Comment: @Matthew *p_func* is a delegate that is used to represent the method named *callback()*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use String as the parameter type, the CLR will not attempt to write any changes back to the native memory buffer. When you use a StringBuilder (which is the right choice for in/out string parameters), it will. But the memory p points to will be read-only because of the way you declared it, that's why yout get an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory