# Understanding C-strings & string literals in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, string-literals, c-strings

I have a few questions I would like to ask about string literals and C-strings.

So if I have something like this:

```
char cstr[] = "c-string";
```

As I understand it, the string literal is created in memory with a terminating null byte, say for example starting at address 0xA0 and ending at 0xA9, and from there the address is returned and/or casted to type char [ ] which then points to the address.

It is then legal to perform this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(char)); ++i)
    cstr[i] = 97+i;
```

So in this sense, are string literals able to be modified as long as they are casted to the type char [ ] ?

But with regular pointers, I've come to understand that when they are pointed to a string literal in memory, they cannot modify the contents because most compilers mark that allocated memory as "Read-Only" in some lower bound address space for constants.

```
char * p = "const cstring";
*p = 'A'; // illegal memory write
```

I guess what I'm trying to understand is why aren't char * types allowed to point to string literals like arrays do and modify their constants? Why do the string literals not get casted into char *'s like they do to char [ ]'s? If I have the wrong idea here or am completely off, feel free to correct me.

Comment: `char * p = "const cstring";` should throw a compilation error, since `"const cstring"` is type `const char*` (specifically so that you don't use it like you're using it in your example)

Comment: @tylerl `"const cstring"` is not of type `const char*`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as of C++11 string literals are of type `const char[N]`, which is perdy much equivalent to `const char*`. You can argue the pedantic details, but that's only adding confusion, not clarity.

Comment: @tylerl On the contrary, those are completely different types, and pretending otherwise is how confusion is introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are creating an actual array of characters, whose size is determined by the size of the literal you are initializing it with (8+1 bytes). The `cstr` variable is allocated memory on the stack, and the *contents* of the string literal (which in the code is located somewhere else, possibly in a read-only part of the memory) is copied into this variable.

In the second case, the local variable `p` is allocated memory on the stack as well, but its contents will be the *address* of the string literal you are initializing it with.

Thus, since the string literal may be located in a read-only memory, it is in general not safe to try to change it via the `p` pointer (you may get along with, or you may not). On the other hand, you can do whatever with the `cstr` array, because that is your local copy that just happens to have been initialized from the literal.

(Just one note: the `cstr` variable is of a type *array of char* and in most of contexts this translates to *pointer to the first element of that array*. Exception to this may be e.g. the `sizeof` operator: this one computes the size of the whole array, not just a pointer to the first element.)

Comment: Ah, I see. So the difference is that one is really just a pointer to the RO memory whilst the other is a variable of array of char (or constant pointer in other words) to a local copy of that literal in memory plus the null byte, and thus access to the copy is RW. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Didn't always used to be RO memory, BTW.  Modifying a "constant" string was an old C programmer's trick, before they started putting the strings in a read-only section.

Answer (score 5):

The bit that you're missing is a little compiler magic where this:

```
char cstr[] = "c-string";
```

Actually executes like this:

```
char *cstr = alloca(strlen("c-string")+1);
memcpy(cstr,"c-string",strlen("c-string")+1);
```

You don't see that bit, but it's more or less what the code compiles to.

Comment: This is definitely what I have been missing! The answer I chose as the selected answer basically put this into words, but the code is even cleaner ;) so really cstr is a const char * to locally allocated memory on the stack (or possibly the heap) that is a copy and is modifiable, unlike the literal string's values. thanks so much for showing me this.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in this case `cstr` is *not* a `const char*` but rather a `char*`. A `const char*` is what you get with string literals. That means that you can't go modifying its contents. In contrast, a `char*` means the data is modifiable. Also, it's very definitely on the stack, not the heap, which is why you don't have to call `free()` on it, and why you can't `return` it to your caller.

Answer (score 2):

`char cstr[] = "something";` is declaring an automatic array ***initialized*** to the bytes 's', 'o', 'm', ...

`char * cstr = "something";`, on the other hand, is declaring a character pointer initialized to the ***address*** of the literal "something".

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this. I see now that arrays, being a standard type, are literally initialized in their constructor by string literals, but are only copies of the literal itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
char cstr[] = "c-string";
```

This copies "c-string" into a char array on the stack. It is legal to write to this memory.

```
char * p = "const cstring";
*p = 'A'; // illegal memory write
```

Literal strings like "c-string" and "const cstring" live in the data segment of your binary. This area is read-only. Above p points to memory in this area and it is illegal to write to that location. Since C++11 this is enforced more strongly than before, in that you *must* make it `const char* p` instead.

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory).