# What does char *x = "geeksquiz" mean?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am pretty new to programming . And I am coming across this declaration a lot.
 Say for example:

`char *x = "geeksquiz";`

Does this mean that x holds the address of first element of the string,i.e, the character 'g' ?

If so then consider the following example:

```
char *str1 = "geeks"; 
char *str2 = "forgeeks"; 
printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2);
```

Output is:

`str1 is geeks, str2 is forgeeks`

How come printf statement prints str1 is geeks and str2 is forgeeks , if they hold addresses respectively ? or is it the placeholder %s that's instructing the printf to print the string literals ?

Comment: Yes. But this no longer valid C++.

Comment: Where are you coming across it? In your C++ book? Which book is it?

Comment: Mandatory preemptive link to accompany Lightness Races in Orbit's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670099/560648

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding C-strings & string literals in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670059/understanding-c-strings-string-literals-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that x holds the address of first element of the string,i.e, the character 'g' ?

Yes.

> is it the placeholder %s that's instructing the printf to print the string literals ?

Yes.

To be more specific, %s is not limited for string literals. It is for printing null terminated srings - which string literals are. Also, it's called a format *specifier*.

---

Considering you've used the tag, note that the expression `char *x = "geeksquiz";` is ill-formed in C++. In C++, the string literal is an array of const char and it doesn't decay to a pointer to non-const char. It is well formed in C, because in that language string literals are non-const.

Answer (score 0):

If this is used in c language then x holds the address of string first character 'g'. You can print it using this code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    char *x="geeksquiz";
    printf("%c",*x);
    return 0;
    }
```

Output : g

Comment: what if I need to print other characters of the string?

Comment: If you want to print other characters of the string then increment pointer                            if you want to print second character then write  printf("%c",*(x+1);