# Pointer to const char vs char array vs std::string

Tags: c++

Here I've two lines of code

```
const char * s1 = "test";
char s2 [] = "test";
```

Both lines of code have the same behavior, so I cannot see any difference whether I should prefer `s1` over `s2` or vice-versa.  In addition to s1 and s2, there is also the way of using `std::string`. I think the way of using std::string is the most elegant. While looking at other code, I often see that people either `use const char *` or `char s []`. Thus, my question is now, when should I use `const char * s1` or `char s []` or `std::string`? What are the differences and in which situations should I use which approach?

Comment: They don't have the same behaviour :-) the first only puts a pointer to a constant string to the stack, and the second puts the whole mutable string on the stack.

Comment: FYI) Type of unprefixed ['string literal'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) such as `"abc"` is 'array of const char', i.e. `const char[N]` (N is the size of the string including the null terminator). This is true for both C and C++ at least right now. To add to Kos's comment right above, string literals have 'static storage duration'(last for the duration of the program). As the standard or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349031/10027592) answer quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const char * s1 = "test";
char s2 [] = "test";
```

These two aren't identical. `s1` is immutable: it points to constant memory. Modifying string literals is undefined behaviour.

And yes, in C++ you should prefer `std::string`.

Comment: Is there are reason why I often see that people use const keyword? Without the const keyword, I get the same behavior, so  char * s1 = "test";. It works fine without any compiler errors ...

Comment: @System.Data see Lightness's answer. The default conversion is deprecated now. It shouldn't be allowed IMO, but it is. It's still UB if you try to modify it.

Comment: @System.Data: Only because you are not using adequate warnings in your build settings. That conversion from `const char*` to `char*` for string literals was allowed in old C (back when it didn't have the safety of `const` _at all_), but is gradually being phased out of C++. So, it's deprecated in C++98/C++03... and downright illegal in C++11. _It's dangerous because it makes you syntactically able to modify the data in the string, whereas in fact it's constant data._

Comment: @System.Data: As a more general protocol, you should **always** use `const` except where you know you don't want to... not the other way around. It's a design flaw rooted in backwards compatibility that C++ names default to mutable rather than immutable.

Answer (score 11):

```
POINTERS
--------

char const* s1 = "test";  // pointer to string literal - do not modify!

char* s1       = "test";  // pointer to string literal - do not modify!
                          //   (conversion to non-const deprecated in C++03 and
                          //       disallowed in C++11)

ARRAYS
------

char s1[5]     = "test";  // mutable character array copied from string literal
                          //    - do what you like with it!

char s1[]      = "test";  // as above, but with size deduced from initialisation



CLASS-TYPE OBJECTS
------------------

std::string s1 = "test";  // C++ string object with data copied from string
                          //    literal - almost always what you *really* want
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one is constant, the second isn't. std::string is a class type and implements many useful functions and methods for string manipulation, making it much easier and user-friendly. The c-style 'strings' with char pointers are difficult to control, manipulate and often cause errors, but don't have the overhead the std::string has. Generally it's better to stick to the std::strings cause they're easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between the two that you should care about is this:

**Which one is your project already using?**

Comment: There is an element of truth to this, but it's _far_ from the primary factor.

Comment: Actually, and unfortunately, it usually is the *only* factor, because you're seldom in a position to chance project policy. Yep, I'm a bit disenchanted that way.

Comment: Development team politics are out of the scope of this question, which is a question about a programming language. Also, if you're not given the opportunity to steer development policies then you're either very junior in a very large team, or in a bad job. (Or both.)

Comment: What I meant was - consistency is among the most valuable things in a codebase. Regardless of any personal opinion in the matter, consistency trumps even things like const correctness.

Answer (score 3):

These two do *not* have the same behavior. `s1` is a simple pointer which is initialized to point to some (usually read-only) area of the memory. `s2`, on the other hand, defines a local array of size 5, and fills it with a copy of this string.

Formally, you are not allowed to modify `s1`, that is, do something like `s1[0] = 'a'`. In particular, under weird circumstances, it could cause all other `"test"`s in your program to become `"aest"`, because they all share the same memory. This is the reason modern compilers yell when you write

```
char* s = "test";
```

On the other hand, modifying `s2` is allowed, since it is a local copy.

In other words, in the following example,

```
const char* s1 = "test";
const char* s2 = "test";
char s3[] = "test";
char s4[] = "test";
```

`s1` and `s2` may very well point to the same address in memory, while `s3` and `s4` are two *different* copies of the same string, and reside in *different* areas of memory.

If you're writing C++, use `std::string` unless you absolutely need an array of characters. If you need a modifiable array of characters, use `char s[]`. If you only need an immutable string, use `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

which one to be used depends upon your requirement. Pointer offers you more flexiblity. and in some cases vulerability. Strings are a safe option and they provide Iterator support.

Comment: In what way do strings "provide STL support"?

Comment: they let you use STL function like search, operations like asignment, acn test for conditions like ==,!= etc

Comment: Assignment and comparison has nothing to do with the STL. The C++ Standard Library's algorithms are pertinent, though, because `std::string` has an iteration interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` unless you **know** why you need a char array / pointer to char.