# What type are "C-style strings" and what's its relationship with std::string

Tags: c++

I was faced with this question for a C++ exam and as much as I think I know the answer, the question confused me enough that I rather have a "Second opinion" per say... haha.

> a) The literal `"Hello, World!"` is a C-Style string. What is its type?
>
> b) Given that the type of C-style string and the type `std::string` are different, how is it possible that the line `std::string hello("Hello,World!");` compiles without errors/warnings (assuming the `<string>` header has been included)?

From my understanding the C-Style string is of type (a) array of chars while `std::string` is of type string... and (b) the reason it compiles is that in C++ the whole casting to chars and all that is done "under the hood" by the type string rather than "in the code".

Am I correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: I suggest you forget the type "string" as it does not exist, it is just a handy representation of an array of characters. Basically it stores the characters and remembers the length (it may store it in different chunks although I don't know any implementation of std::string that actually does that). That's why there're interchanged easily.

Comment: @demorge: for what it's worth, non-contiguous storage for `std::string` (or any other instantiation of `std::basic_string`) has been banned in C++11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you say is probably close enough to be called "true", although you're missing some detail. The type of the literal `"Hello, World!"` in C++ is `const char[14]`. As you say that's an array of chars, but the size is part of the type.

`std::string` has a constructor that takes `const char*`, and there's an implicit conversion from `const char[14]` to `const char*`. Those two together handle (b).

There's no "casting to chars" involved, though.

Comment: possible to assume that above literal have type `static const char[14]` according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory ?

Comment: @triclosan: you're right that string literals have static storage duration, but storage class specifiers aren't part of the type.

Comment: yea, I didn't know how to explain myself too well back there lol. Thanks Steve!

Comment: @triclosan: `static` is a linkage modifier, it is not part of the object's type.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the type of `"Hello, World!"` is an array of 14 `const char`  and in C the type is an array of 14 `char`. The trailing null character of the string is a part of the array.

Comment: what I get from what u said is that in C++ you couldn't change 1 char in the "Hello, World!" string while in C style you could technically switch a character manually since its just an array of char(s) rather than const char(s)?

Comment: @Gal: it's still undefined behavior in C to modify a string literal (i.e: it's forbidden by the language), but the type system doesn't stop you. The authors of the C standard have more concern than the authors of the C++ standard for pre-standard or defective C code that takes a `char*` parameter where it could take a `const char*`, for an argument that it doesn't modify. If existing code passes in a string literal, then changing the type of the string literal from `char[N]` to `const char[N]` breaks the code. C never made that breaking change, despite `const` being part of the first standard.