# C++ map::find char * vs. char []

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I'm using C++ map to implemented a dictionary in my program. My function gets a structure as an argument and should return the associated value based on `structure.name` member which is `char named[32]`. The following code demonstrates my problem:

```
map <const char *, const char *> myMap;
myMap.insert(pair<const char *, const char *>("test", "myTest"));

char *p = "test";
char buf[5] = {'\0'};
strcpy(buf, "test");

cout << myMap.find(p)->second << endl; // WORKS
cout << myMap.find("test")->second << endl; // WORKS
cout << myMap.find(buf)->second << endl; // DOES NOT WORK
```

I am not sure why the third case doesn't work and what should I do to make it work.
I debugged the above code to watch the values passed and I still cannot figure the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointer comparison, not string comparison, will be performed by `map` to locate elements. The first two work because `"test"` is a string literal and will have the same address. The last does not work because `buf` will not have the same address as `"test"`.

To fix, either use a `std::string` or define a comparator for `char*`.

Comment: Actually, it's implementation-defined whether two string literals with the same characters have the same address. So `"test" == "test"` may be false. Also, string literals may overlap, so `"confusion" + 3 == "fusion"` may be true.

Answer (score 5):

The map key is a pointer, not a value. All your literal "test" strings share storage, because the compiler is clever that way, so their pointers are the same, but `buf` is a different memory address.

You need to use a map key that has value equality semantics, such as `std::string`, instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

Like was mentioned you are comparing on the address not the value.  I wanted to link this article:

[Is a string literal in c++ created in static memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory)

Since all the literals had the same address this explains why your comparison of string literals worked even though the underlying type is still a `const char *` (but depending on the compiler it may not ALWAYS be so)

Answer (score 0):

Its because by buf[5] you are allocating the memory pointed by buf but when u use 'p' pointer it points to the same memory location as used by map. So always use std::string in key instead of pointer variable.