# Converting a Constant Char to a char C++

Tags: c++

Here is the beginning of my program that makes long strings of 10. Every time I try to set bigfor to "0" it says it needs to be converted from a constant char to a char. How is this done?

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main () {



char bigfor[10];
int arrayvar = 0;
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;
int g;
int h;
int i;
int j;

// Constants

int variable1 = 0;
int variable2 = 1;
int variable3 = 2;
int variable4 = 3;
int variable5 = 4;
int variable6 = 5;
int variable7 = 6;
int variable8 = 7;
int variable9 = 8;
int variable10 = 9;






for (a=0; a < 36; a++)

{

switch (a)

 {
case 0:
  bigfor[variable1] = "0";
   break;
 case 1:
  bigfor[variable1] = "1";
   break;
 case 2:
  bigfor[variable1] = "2";
   break;
 case 3:
  bigfor[variable1] = "3";
   break;
 case 4:
  bigfor[variable1] = "4";
   break;
 case 5:
  bigfor[variable1] = "5";
   break;
 case 6:
  bigfor[variable1] = "6";
   break;
 case 7:
  bigfor[variable1] = "7";
   break;
 case 8:
  bigfor[variable1] = "8";
   break;
 case 9:
  bigfor[variable1] = "9";
   break;
}


 ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("codes.txt");
  myfile << bigfor[variable1];
  myfile << bigfor[variable2];
  myfile << bigfor[variable3];
  myfile << bigfor[variable4];
  myfile << bigfor[variable5];
  myfile << bigfor[variable6];
  myfile << bigfor[variable7];
  myfile << bigfor[variable8];
  myfile << bigfor[variable9];
  myfile << bigfor[variable10];
  myfile << '\n';
  myfile.close();


}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried strcpy yet? std::string.c_str()?

Comment: You're writing uninitialized elements to the file.

Comment: `bigfor[0]` is a char. `"0"` is a string literal, which has type "array of n const char" and static storage duration according to 2.13.4/1 in the Standard (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/349031/96780) for more details). You cannot assign the latter to the former. You may assign `'0'`, though, which _is_ a char.

Comment: `My` `eyes` `cried` `out` `in` `agony`.

Answer (score 4):

`bigfor` is an array of type `char`, but you're putting strings into it.

Text between double quotes, such as `"0"` are interpreted by the compiler to be literal strings.

Text between single quotes such as `'0'` are interpreted by the compiler to be literal chars.

So when you add chars to `bigfor`, you should use **single quotes** to tell the compiler that they are `char`s, instead of strings.

```
bigfor[variable1] = '0';
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misreading the error. What it tells you is that it cannot convert `const char *` (pointer to `const char`, i.e. a C string) to `char` (a single character).

A literal such as `"0"` represents a zero-terminated constant array of characters and, when used in an expression, converts to a pointer to the first character in the array. What you want is a single character, which is represented by single quotes: `'0'` instead of `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the characters but you are filling a literal String.Try this way

```
bigfor[variable1] = '0'
```