# Win32 SendMessage between threads

Tags: multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, message

I have a worker thread which collects data from an external device. The worker thread keeps the main thread with the UI informed about its state. 
For this I'm using variations of:

```
SendMessage( hwndParentThread, WM_NOTIFY, 0, TEXT("Connection successful.")).
```

Now, the debugger complains about a memory leak. As I'm not really sure about what happens with the memory allocated for the strings I'm wondering  whether the leak stems from the strings I pass between the threads (e.g. `TEXT("Connection successful.")`).

If anyone could point me into the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ Literal text constants have static location (e.g. memory for "Connection successful." string is not allocated during function call). See this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/349031/1025209.

I can't see any problems with your line of code. Is the memory leak exactly in this line?

Comment: Well I'm not really sure, but now I know where to not look.
Thanks
Manfred