# replacing chars with memmove in char pointer

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

I am trying to understand why this works:

```
char myst1r[] = "hello\n";
memmove(myst1r   , myst1r + 1 , 1 );//results in "eello"
```

while this one :

```
char *mystr = "hello\n";
memmove(mystr , mystr + 1 , 1 );
```

results in "Access violation writing location" error.
Don't both `myst1r` and `mystr` point to the first member of char buffer? What do I miss here?

Comment: Please explain why you downvote? This is completely valid SO question.

Comment: @MichaelV It's a duplicate a lot of times, it has been overasked. Downvoters presumably have the feeling that you haven't dony any research before asking. Also, anybody with a minimal understanding of the difference between arrays and pointers (and especially string constants) wouldn't have had to ask this question.

Comment: It was asked in conjunction with char arrays which is indeed clear...In my case I was trying to work on char pointer.

Comment: _"Please explain why you downvote"_, put your mouse cursor on down arrow, that probably explains it

Comment: Please show me similar question?The one mentioned above DOESN"T deal with memmove.But whatever...I have understood what I needed from the answers.Some of you guys here are too tough.Even if this issue was answered indirectly in some other case does't mean such a question can't be valid.C/C++ noobs are also people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myst1r` is an **array** of `char` that holds a **copy** of its initializer. `mystr` is a **pointer** to `char` that points to its initializer. In both cases, the initializer is a literal string. The difference is that you can modify the contents of an array, but you cannot modify the contents of a literal string.

Comment: So  does it mean I can't use memmove to modify char buffer pointer?

Comment: No, that's not what it means. What you can't do is **modify a string literal**. A string literal is a quoted string: `"hello\n"`, for example. If you have a pointer that points to modifiable text you can use `memmove`.

Comment: Also the error code "access violation at writing location" makes sense because String literals are put in read only segments by compilers.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam - maybe, maybe not. The rule is that the behavior is undefined. On some systems it works just fine; on others it does not.

Comment: @PeteBecker some time back I read it. May be this was the question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory and the top voted answer says it

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam - the first sentence of the top voted answer is "Where it's created is an implementation decision by the compiler writer, really." The language definition does **not** require that string literals be put in read-only memory, although that's quite common.

Answer (score 2):

```
h e l l o \0
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

The code

```
memmove(myst1r, myst1r + 1, 1 )
```

copies the character at place 1 (`e`) to place 0. Results in `eello`.

As for the second example

```
char *mystr = "hello\n";
```

`mystr` here is a string literal, modifying it leads to undefined behavior in both C and C++.

Just a little note, using `memcpy` to replace `memmove` will not work because the first two parameters overlap.