# What's the difference between defining a string as an array or as a char pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

When I execute the code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ( ){
    char string [] = "Home Sweet Home";
    printf ("%s",(char*)memmove(string,&string[5],10));
    }
```

the output is "Sweet Home Home".

But;
when I change the code like below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( )
{
    char* string = "Home Sweet Home";
    printf ("%s",(char*)memmove(string,&string[5],10));

}
```

it gives segmentation fault.

What changes when I define this array as a char pointer?

Comment: `string` in 2nd case points to memory that should not be attempted to be changed.

Comment: But for what you are saying shouldn't I have used const at the beginning?

Comment: And some string functions can be used when defined like the 2nd one

Comment: Any attempt to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*. In the second case your pointer `string` points to the first character of such a literal string. That's the reason all such pointers are recommended to be `const`, as in `const char *string`.

Comment: Code could have used `const char* string = "Home Sweet Home";` then the compiler should warn/error about `memmove(string,&string[5],10)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if so is there a way to modify these kind of defined strings?

Comment: @burr4ch Except copy them into an array you define yourself, and modify your own array? No, there's no way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacing chars with memmove in char pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944312/replacing-chars-with-memmove-in-char-pointer)

Comment: burr4ch, "the difference between defining a string as an array or as a char pointer?" implies a mis-understanding.  A _string_ is not a pointer.  Pointers to _strings_ are often used as in the 2nd case - in that case incorrectly.  Also trouble with "when I define this array as a char pointer" --> An array is not a pointer, a pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What changes when I define this array as a char pointer?

In this case the most importantly: the mutability of the data changes.

```
char string [] = "Home Sweet Home";
```

The `"Home Sweet Home"` here is an [*initializer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) for array `string`. It initializes the string with the characters with zero terminating character. The array size is inferred from the initializer, (if I count right) that's 16 characters. Array `string` is declared as `char`, so it mutable and you can change it.

```
char* string = "Home Sweet Home";
```

The `"Home Sweet Home"` here is a [*string literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). String literals are immutable, not modifiable, cannot be modified. A pointer to the string literal is stored in `string` pointer. Modifying a string literal results in undefined behavior. Segmentation fault is the error, when a program accesses a memory location that it is not allowed to access. In this case the program tries to write to a memory location that it is not allowed to modify.

Comment: Detail: "String literals .... cannot be modified." and "Modifying a string literal results in undefined behavior." are in conflict.  Attempting to modify is UB.  It might work, might not, might crash, ...   It is UB.

Comment: chux is correct, and it is important to get the semantics correct. The C standard says it does not define the behavior of attempting to modify a string literal. Telling somebody it is immutable can cause them to make incorrect deductions when diagnosing a bug in a C implementation where the implementation does not prevent a string literal from being modified. It is incorrect to assert, without qualification, that string literals are immutable or that they are not modifiable or that they cannot be modified.