# Can reassigning a C style string cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, string

Can reassigning a C style string cause a memory leak? Like so:

```
char * s = "Hello!";
s = "Hello, world!";
```

My question may appear as stupid, but please bear with me; I am currently still a dummie in C++.

In the second line of code, the C style string `s` is longer, so does it have it internally reallocate memory? Does this cause a memory leak? And do I have to call `delete`?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot re-assign a char* like that.

Comment: You're assigning pointers, not the actual values.  And the actual values are literals generated by the compiler and hence are not heap allocated.

Comment: Note that you can't do something like `*s = ...`

Comment: (It's really important to understand the difference between `some_data` and a pointer to `some_data`.)

Comment: @user2672165: yes you can.

Comment: @user2672165, why not?

Comment: It should actually be `const char *s = ...`, because string literals are pointers to non-modifiable (constant) memory

Comment: @6502: Ok. I guess I learnt somethin then:) I don't if I will use it. It is with char array it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, technically no.  String literals are provided special static allocation.  See

[Is a string literal in c++ created in static memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-c-created-in-static-memory)

Answer (score 3):

[Memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) are caused by dynamic memory allocation.

There is no dynamic allocation here, so **no memory leak**.

Actually, *string literals* have *static storage duration*. The standard says (draft n3690):

> **3.7.1 Static storage duration [basic.stc.static]**
>
> All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have static storage duration. **The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the program**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dynamic memory allocation so there is no leak. What you have is a pointer pointing to a string literal which is stored somewhere in implementation defined read only memory.