Difference between a mutable and immutable string
I just started studying C++, but there is a thing that I don't fully understand: when you initialize a std::string variable with a string literal, like this:
std::string str = "some string";

We have the literal "some string", which is immutable.
Then we have the variable str that stores "some string" and is mutable. You can go there and append another string to it, change letters, etc.
The whole point is: when we initialize str with this literal, it does a modifiable copy of the literal to this variable? If so, that means that in memory, there are two spaces: one to the "some string" literal and another for the modifiable "some string"?
And, just to make it clear: a value is a literal just if it is hard-coded in the source code, is it not?

The standard did not define anything about that! It might be, that the string after init is only a pointer to the "original" and if it should be modified it will be copied/changed. BTW: Most implementations use a short string optimization which stores the string inside the string object without allocating heap. As you can see: It depends :-)

In your code "some string" is a constant. It won't consume any memory by itself until it is stored in your variable i.e., str. If you do not initialize str, then it theoretically won't use memory and probably will be eliminated by compiler during optimization if it is not used anywhere in your code.

Let's add some more confusion:  const std::string read_only_str = "read_only";

Yes, there will be two copies. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vzK8Ej47a you can see the fixed string. It’s assigned to the global variable which has a copy that can be modified.

Assigning a string literal to std::string

The standard (roughly speaking) only stipulates observable behaviour and an implementation can do anything it likes (omit unused variables, etc) as long as it meet requirements.  There is also nothing preventing some form of "compiler magic" to construct str without maintaining the literal in memory.  Such possibilities are optional, and amount to "quality of implementation" concerns - compilers can do such things (at a cost, for example, of effort developing the compiler and also compilation time).   But, practically, will not if the cost is considered too great and benefit too low.

"some string" is a string literal of type const char[12].  In certain contexts, like in a function parameter, an array decays into a pointer to its 1st element.  In this case, to a const char* pointer.
std::string str = "some string"; is just syntax sugar, it is functionally identical to std::string str("some string");  It calls the std::string constructor which takes a const char* as input.  That constructor does indeed make a copy of the character data into its own memory.  Depending on your compiler's std::string implementation, that will either be in:

dynamic memory held outside of the std::string object, but pointed at by an internal member of the object.

an SSO (Short String Optimization) buffer located in automatic memory within the std::string object itself.


So yes, there will be 2 copies of "some string" in memory, somewhere.
And yes, a literal is a value that is hard-coded in the source code itself.  The compiler will translate the value into the appropriate type and memory storage as needed.

I was under the impression that since C++11 SSO is not possible anymore. Am I wrong?

@bolov Yes, you are wrong. Just about every modern implementation uses SSO (with various buffer sizes, depending on implementation).  Maybe you are thinking of COW (Copy-On-Write) instead?

yes, I was mixing things up and thinking about COW. Thank you for the clarification.

Will anything be done about the first "some string"? Won’t it be gotten rid of? Yes??

@ChukwujiobiCanon string literals exist for the lifetime of the program, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/

Yeah I thought so too according to the standard but that’s just a bad waste of space in the case of constructing an std::string.

@ChukwujiobiCanon well, a string literal's data has to come from somewhere, it doesn't just materialize out of thin air. And what if you needed to create multiple std::strings with the same value?  If you are really worried about memory usage then use std::string_view or std::span instead, as they are just pointers to existing memory, they don't allocate anything.


it does a modifiable copy of the literal to this variable? If so, that means that in memory, there are two spaces: one to the "some string" literal and another for the modifiable "some string"?

You got it.  But the compiler is free to make optimizations. At runtime, with retail/relase optimizations turned out (e.g. -O2), the compiler can make smart determinations if it really needs to copy the string - especially if s never actually gets mutated. But as a programmer, work with the assumption that the compiler isn't as smart as you.
